# Accessing Arrays throughout classes xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

In my xcode project, whenever I try using:

```
#import "Class1.h"
NSMutableArray *array;
@implementation Class2
Class1 *class = [Class1 new];
array = class.array;
```

Assuming there is something called array in Class1.
Xcode builds it like there are no errors. However, when I run it, the screen flashes what is on class1 before crashing and giving me an error.
I fixed some other code. Now the error is:

```
[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
```

Sorry, I am new to Obj-C.

Comment: What you want to do?Do you want global array?? or something else like you described in question.

Comment: mov.... is the dubug part, i asked for error in console if any? And Please post your full code. Ad from this snippet, it is very difficult to check in which method you are creating class and whether you are alloc+init-ing array etc..

Comment: @AnoopVaidya just in case it is needed, this is a CCNode(from cocos2d) class. Would that change anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Designing your code. Design Pattern. These should be decided first, and thereafter coding is simpler.

As I can see you are creating a global array!!! Which is not good. If you want a shared array use SingletonClass/SharedClass.

Or you should put `NSMutableArray *array;` in `.h` file and alloc+init it to access it.

```
array = [class array];
```

This line is not clear, `[class array]` will return the array of Class1, so you must have NSArray in your Class2 where you are assiging Class1's array.

If Class2 has array as property use `self.array=[class array];`

Answer (score 0):

If you want your array to be a property of Class1, you need to do something like this in your Class1.h file:

```
@interface Class1

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;

@end
```

Then you can access the array like in the code you posted.

Comment: new is equivalant to alloc+init. That statement is perfectly valid in Obj-C.